# Being $X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}$ independent random variables with mean and variance $\mu,\sigma^{2}$ Is defined: $U_{n}=n^{a}(\overline X_{n}{-\mu})^2$

Tags: probability, statistics

Where $\overline X_{n}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}}{n}$, and $a\in (0,1)$.

Prove that $U_{n}$ converges to a constant $"c"$ in probability. And find $"c"$

So we have to prove $P(|U_{n}-c|>\epsilon) \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$

How can I solve this?. I solved asymptotic theory exercises before,  but this one is different because I do not see where can apply a theorem like Slutsky, Weak law of the great numbers etc.

Comment: Are you sure this statement is true? (And what type of convergence is it referring to?) When $a=1/2$, the central limit theorem implies that $U_n$ converges in distribution to $N(0, \sigma^2)$, which is not a constant.

Comment: It had a typo. I changed the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice by the central limit theorem, that we have the following convergence in distribution
$$n^{1/2}(\bar{X}_n-\mu) \rightarrow Z \sim N(0,\sigma^2).$$
Since $z\mapsto z^2$ is continuous, we then get that
$$n(\bar{X}_n - \mu)^2 \rightarrow Z^2 \sim \sigma^2 \chi^2_{(1)}.$$
Notice now, that
$$n^a(X_n-\mu)^2 = n^{a-1} \cdot n(\bar{X}_n - \mu)^2 \rightarrow  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^{a-1} \cdot Z^2 = 0,$$
where we used slutsky's theorem and the fact that $n^{a-1}\rightarrow 0$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$, when $a\in(0,1)$. Furthermore, since the limit is a constant, we get that convergence in distribution and in probability are equivalent, and therefore $U_n$ converges to $0$ in probability as well.

Comment: Thank you! I got it

Answer (score 1):

- $U_n = \frac{1}{n^{1-a}} (\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n - \mu))^2$
- Let $Z \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. We know from the Central Limit Theorem that $\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n - \mu)$ converges in distribution to $Z$. By the continuous mapping theorem, $(\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n - \mu))^2$ converges in distribution to $Z^2$.
- By Slutsky's theorem, $\frac{1}{n^{1-a}} (\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n - \mu))^2$ converges in distribution to $0$.

Comment: Thank you! I got ir¿t